# Kafka - Multiple consumers (only one active) on same group/topic

Tags: apache-kafka, mapr-streams

Is it possible to have multiple copies of an application listen to the same Kafka group/topic so that only one is reading it at a time, but the other ones will start working if the main one crashes/stops reading?

I need to make an application highly available but can't tolerate doubling the traffic to the data store on the other end of the application by having multiple copies actively running.

FYI - Technically I'm using MapR streams but it adheres to the Kafka API and functionality, in case anyone knows a MapR stream-specific feature that helps the situation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible. If multi consumers are in same consumer group, when the group subscribes a topic, kafka will do a partition assignment work for your consumers: one partition could only be consumed by only one consumer in a same group.

So you could set your topic to have only one partition, then only one consumer to consume message, others will be idle. Once the consumer is shutdown, it will trigger the group rebalance operation : kafka will do the partition assignment again. And Then in your case , a new consumer will go ahead this work. It will process message from the last committed offset which commited by old consumer.

And if your case supports parallel processing, you could make many process(app) doing same   work and set the topic to multi partitions. They will be assigned to consume different partitions and process different messages. So it will speed up your process and also can tolerant the fail over. As above said, if some consumers is failed, kafka will take care it for you, it will assign their paritition to other  working consumer. So everything will be ok.

Comment: Awesome.  I was just reading that on this confluence page I found too :). https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Consumer+Group+Example.  Thank you for your answer!